# Error LNK 2028 and 2001

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, linker, c++-cli, lnk2001

I am working on a project with Windows Forms in Visual C++ 2010. I am using the [BasicExcel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13852/BasicExcel-A-Class-to-Read-and-Write-to-Microsoft) class. Here is the relevant code:

I include the header file:

```
#include "BasicExcel.hpp"
using namespace YExcel;
```

Then I have the software write "Test str1" at the cell 1,4 when I push a button:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         //Code for Writing to Excel
            BasicExcel x;
        // Load a workbook with one sheet, write some test data at (1,4)
            x.Load("TestFile.xlsx");
            BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = x.GetWorksheet("Sheet1");
            BasicExcelCell* cell;
            sheet->Cell(1,4)->SetString("Test str1");
     }
```

When I do this I get the following errors:

```
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000020) "public: class    YExcel::BasicExcelCell * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(unsigned int,unsigned     int)" (?Cell@BasicExcelWorksheet@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelCell@2@II@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005A) "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelCell * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?Cell@BasicExcelWorksheet@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelCell@2@II@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000021) "public: void __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelCell::SetString(char const *)" (?SetString@BasicExcelCell@YExcel@@$$FQAMXPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005B) "public: void __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelCell::SetString(char const *)" (?SetString@BasicExcelCell@YExcel@@$$FQAMXPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000022) "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::GetWorksheet(char const *)" (?GetWorksheet@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelWorksheet@2@PBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005C) "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::GetWorksheet(char const *)" (?GetWorksheet@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelWorksheet@2@PBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000023) "public: bool __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::Load(char const *)" (?Load@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005D) "public: bool __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::Load(char const *)" (?Load@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000024) "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::~BasicExcel(void)" (??1BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005E) "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::~BasicExcel(void)" (??1BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000025) "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::BasicExcel(void)" (??0BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00005F) "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::BasicExcel(void)" (??0BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::~BasicExcel(void)" (??1BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::~BasicExcel(void)" (??1BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelCell::SetString(char const *)" (?SetString@BasicExcelCell@YExcel@@$$FQAMXPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelCell::SetString(char const *)" (?SetString@BasicExcelCell@YExcel@@$$FQAMXPBD@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelCell * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?Cell@BasicExcelWorksheet@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelCell@2@II@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelCell * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?Cell@BasicExcelWorksheet@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelCell@2@II@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::GetWorksheet(char const *)" (?GetWorksheet@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelWorksheet@2@PBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet * __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::GetWorksheet(char const *)" (?GetWorksheet@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAMPAVBasicExcelWorksheet@2@PBD@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::Load(char const *)" (?Load@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::Load(char const *)" (?Load@BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM_NPBD@Z)
1>Agricultural_Software.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::BasicExcel(void)" (??0BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Agricultural_Software::EnterLoads::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@EnterLoads@Agricultural_Software@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Enter Loads.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall YExcel::BasicExcel::BasicExcel(void)" (??0BasicExcel@YExcel@@$$FQAM@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Agricultural Software\Agricultural_Software\Release\Agricultural_Software.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried to get it fixed but I don't know much about linking. I would appreciate it if someone would enlighten me. 
Thanks!

Comment: You include a header file, but have you added any potential source files to your project?

Comment: Thank you! That was really simple. I should have been able to figure that one out, but all the solutions to these linker errors were very long complicated posts that seemed project specific. Thanks again!